# Выбор направления работы с hash-алгоритмом

Tags: хеширование, password-hash

Здравствуйте.

У меня есть тема "Модернизация алгоритма хеширования пользовательских данных", но как я понимаю, звучит она довольно таки неоднозначно.

До сего момента о хешировании нам рассказывали довольно таки посредственно. И я не имею конкретного понятия о масштабах работы. Я так понимаю, можно либо совершенствовать уже имеющийся в наличии алгоритм хеширования, что, как по мне, задача не из простых. Или же описать какой-то метод (общий) совершенствования - возможную его доработку. Также существует вероятность создания hash-алгоритма, скажем доселе невиданного, как если бы я его придумал могу описать принцип, но без програмной реализации.

Как вы считаете реально ли за три месяца сделать работу в одном из вышеупомянутых направлений? Возможно, последний вариант наиболее оптимален?

Если имеете еще какие-нибудь возможные варианты, буду благодарен. Спасибо.

Comment: Всё уже придумано за нас. "...Также существует вероятность создания hash-алгоритма, скажем доселе невиданного..." - флаг в руки. На счет 3-х месяцев - хз. Может вы гений? Электроник? ))

Comment: Интересно, что понимается под "модернизацией", что там можно модернизировать, увеличивать крипто-надежность хеша, улучшать распределение или например придумать очень быстрый алгоритм (с малой крипто-стойкостью конечно)

Comment: @AIex, электроник.

Comment: @Mike, насколько вообще трудно увеличить крипто-надежность или распределение. Я читал в интернете о том, что быстрые алгоритмы довольно таки слабы с точки зрения криптографии. Понимаю, звучит странно, но все же. Такова тема, теперь пытаюсь найти решение. Что бы вы посоветовали мне, будь вы на моем месте?

Comment: Не знаю, не пробовал. надо глубоко изучать существующие алгоритмы.

Comment: @Mike, давайте поговорим напрямую. Бакалаврская дипломная работа - вещь довольно таки странная: с одной стороны - ненужная работа, попытка сделать что-то еще не выданное, но все работающее едва ли можно усовершенствовать; и все же при этом надо проявить некую креативность дабы удовлетворить само определение работи. Скажем я задумаю написать алгоритм с малой криптостойкостью, но работающий быстро.

Comment: @Mike, для этого необходимо будет прочитать различные статьи, но все же это выполнимо, не так ли? На ваш взгляд, это выполнимо? Если да, то согласны ли вы будете меня консультировать? Если мне понадобиться ваша помощь? Конечно, единственное что вы получите это интерес за процесом, если таковой будет, но я дерзну задать вам этот вопрос.

Comment: @MuscledBoy что за бред вы читали про скорость алгоритмов и надежность? Все современные хеш-функции очень быстрые и очень надежные. Тот же SHA-256 взять в пример. Да, там возможно length-extension атака, но она уж точно никак не связана со скоростью работы.

Comment: @Zergatul Вы просто скорость не с тем сравниваете. Вернее сравниваете ее видимо только внутри криптографических хеш-функций. Но кроме них есть другие классы хеш-функций, которые на порядки быстрее криптографических, на подобии CRC или Дженкинса. И с этой точки зрения - хочешь криптографически стойкое, жертвуешь скоростью

Comment: @Mike да, я имел ввиду только криптографические хеш-функции

Comment: @Mike, тогда буду читать информацию.